# displaying message in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function () {
   
   var fname = $("#fname").val();
   var lname = $("#lname").val();
   var email = $("#email").val();
   var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
   
   if(fname == ""){
     alert('First Name is required');
     return false;
   }
   else if(lname == ""){
    alert("Last Name is required");
    return false;
   }
   else if(email == ""){
          alert("Email is required");
     return false;
   }
   
   else(fname == "" && lname == "" && email == ""){
    alert("All Fields are required");
    return false;

   }
   
      
  });
```

```html
<form id="form1" action=""  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Basic Info</legend>
                      
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">First Name *</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="" placeholder="Enter First Name" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Last Name *</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" value="" placeholder="Enter Last Name" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
   </div>
 </div>          
</div>
             
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Email *</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter Email" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
     </div>
  </div>
 
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Mobile #</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" placeholder="+55 99 99999999" data-type="alphanum" maxlength="45"/>
   </div>
 </div>          
</div>
             
 <div class="row" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="status">Status</label>
     <div>
    <span class="text-muted m-l-5">InActive</span>
  <input type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" id="status" name="status" data-theme="default" checked />
    <span class="text-muted m-l-5">Active</span>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="status">All Permissions</label>
     <div>
    <span class="text-muted m-l-5">No</span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-render="switchery" id="status" name="status" data-theme="default" checked />
   <span class="text-muted m-l-5">Yes</span>
    </div>
    </div>         

    </div>         
    </div> 
    </fieldset> 

 <div class="row pull-right">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-r-5" id="btnSave" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Process...">Save</button>
<a href="http://localhost/granplay-v3/index.php/managers" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </div>
                      
  </form>
```

In `if elsif else` condition the else condition does not alert the message for all fields. when i comment out the last else condition it shows every field condition message. but not for,suppose user did not input anything fields, showing the alert message for all fields.
**so my question is : why else condition does not alert the message?**

Comment: In `else` you can't write conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order and try. Put that `else` condition `first` :

```
if( fname == "" && lname == "" && email == "") {
    alert("All Fields are required");
    return false;

} eles if(fname == ""){
    alert('First Name is required');
    return false;

} else if(lname == ""){
    alert("Last Name is required");
    return false;

} else if(email == ""){
    alert("Email is required");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just move your else part in first if

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function () {
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var mobile = $("#mobile").val();

        if(fname == "" && lname == "" && email == ""){
            alert("All Fields are required");
            return false;
        }else if(fname == ""){
            alert('First Name is required');
            return false;
        }
        else if(lname == ""){
            alert("Last Name is required");
            return false;
        }
        else if(email == ""){
            alert("Email is required");
            return false;
        }else{
            alert("All fields are filled");
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

If all fields were blank, your first condition will be true, and if any one of them is filled, first condition will be wrong so it will check in another `if-else` parts.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just a control flow problem, nothing more

Comment: Yes, @JordanQuartermain, We just need to check the flow of conditions from all blank to all filled.

Comment: Ok it means its control flow problem like @JordanQuartermain said.

Comment: but one i don't need to show the last else condition.

Comment: i think i will have to get rid of the last else condtion. like the below answer.

Comment: I just added that last else part when everything is ok!!! My Mistake. lost some reputations ;) :D ... Never Mind :)